# CKEditor and CakePHP change height

Tags: css, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, ckeditor

I am developing with CakePHP and want to modify height of CKEditor generated with cake html helper, because I need to have two editors inside one page, with different height.

How I can do this with css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I remember that you can do when you define ckeditor js in your view e.g.

ed = CKEDITOR.replace("textarea", 
{
height:"291", width:"400"
});

check this documentation:

http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.width

http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=13810

Regards.

Comment: oh! yeah, you only need to edit the id of the textarea to adding all you want.
CKEDITOR.replace(
"id1", { height:"291", width:"400" }
"id2", { height:"200", width:"300" }
"id3", { height:"325", width:"290" }
);
it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     CKEDITOR.replace( 'texarea', height:'350px',autoGrow_minHeight:'350px'});
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     CKEDITOR.replace( 'texarea', height:'350px',autoGrow_minHeight:'100%'});
</script>
```